# Objective-C How to create dictionary for each segment index and how to display dictionary values of selected index in UITableview

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a `UISegmentControl` with two index namely top news and sports news. For each index how do I create NSDictionary and how to display the NSDictionary values in `UITableview` when segment section selected?.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this code:

```
@interface YourViewController (){

    NSMutableArray *arrNewsList;
    NSMutableDictionary * dict;

}

- (IBAction)switchManageAssige:(id)sender {

   switch (_switchManageAssige.selectedSegmentIndex)
   {
       case 0:
           arrNewsList=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[dict objectForKey:@"News"]];
         [_tableView reloadData];

          break;
      case 1:
          arrNewsList=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[dict objectForKey:@"sport"]];
         [_tableView reloadData];

          break;
   }


}
```

Comment: arrayNewList = [dict objectForKey:@"News"] will do the same?

Comment: can you alloc array?

Comment: You dont have to alloc array if you are assigning it with an another arary, can you try it?